# Filtering dataframe rows as reading in CSV with multiprocessing

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to parse the data from the CSV's before loading it into RAM? Currently, I am loading all the data, combining all of it, and then selecting rows I need. Would it be faster to select my rows per file before concating?

Here is my code to load the df:

```py
import pandas as pd 
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool

def my_read_csv(filename):
    return pd.read_csv(filename)

def load_csv():
    path = *my path**
    listOfFiles = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*_T100D_*.csv"))
    
    print('Beginning to combine df')
    print('...working...')
    start_time = time.time()
    
    with Pool(processes=8) as pool:
        df_list = pool.map(my_read_csv, listOfFiles)
       
    df = pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True, sort=True)
    print("Pooled process took", time.time() - start_time, " seconds to run")
    
    return df
```

There are two columns in df that are `YEAR` and `ORIGIN`. How can I parse it so that only `df.YEAR >= 2004` and `df.isin(['LAX', 'JFK'])` are read into the df?

Answer (score 0):

You can potentially try `dask` to filter out the data first and then transform to a pandas dataframe. I created two sample .csv files to test successfully, but let me know how it works for you. I have also taken out the multiprocessing code as you might not need that with `dask`.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd #try using dask
import glob
import os
import pandas as pd 
import time

def load_csv():
    path = r'Desktop/'
    listOfFiles = glob.glob(f'{path}*_T100D_*.csv')
    print('...working...')
    start_time = time.time()
    df = dd.concat([dd.read_csv(f) for f in listOfFiles]) #changed pd to dd
    print("Process took", time.time() - start_time, " seconds to run")
    df = df[(df.YEAR >= 2004) & (df.ORIGIN.isin(['LAX', 'JFK']))].compute() #filter for rows and compute as pandas dataframe
    return df


load_csv()
```

---

```
...working...
Pooled process took 0.01399993896484375  seconds to run
Out[25]: 
   YEAR ORIGIN
3  2004    JFK
6  2007    LAX
0  2008    LAX
2  2010    LAX
3  2011    JFK
6  2014    LAX
```

Comment: What is the benefit of using dask? Also, I would like to keep the multiprocessing because I am loading several GB of data from different files.

Comment: Massive Memory/Speed improvements are the benefits. You should try it out. I tried multi-processing in the past but dask was a much better solution for my particular problem.